# A piecewise $C^1$ curve has Jordan measure zero.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbb{R}}\gamma:[0,1]\to \Reals^2$ is an injective parametrization of a curve $\Gamma$, which is piecewise $C^1$ and the length of the curve is $L(\Gamma_k)<\infty$.

1.1.: Show that for every $n\in N$ there is a decomposition $0=t_0<t_1< \dots <t_n=1$ of $[0,1]$ so that $L(\Gamma_k) = \frac{L}{n}$ for $k=1,\dots ,n$ and $\Gamma_k=\operatorname{Im}(\gamma_k)$, $\gamma_k=\gamma|_{[t_{k-1},t_k]}$.

1.2.: Show that you can cover $\Gamma$ with a system of spheres of radius $\frac{L}{n}$.

1.3.: Use 1.2. and 1.3. to show that $\Gamma$ has Jordan measure zero.

I wasn't there when they discussed when a function has Jordan measure zero  and how those things correlate with this exercise so if someone could give me some hints that would be great.

Comment: Would this be better suited for [math.se]?

Comment: I would think so too, but I thought since we got this exercise in physics it would have some relation to physics. But the Prof is also heavily using advanced mathematics in all parts of his lectures even though it's not needed so I am not sure.

Comment: Advanced math is always better ;) But, really, this is for math.SE!

Comment: That's true. I think I will just post this into Math.SE then.

Comment: @Rab: A set $\Gamma$ has Jordan measure zero if $\Gamma$ can be covered by _finitely many_ sets (such as closed disks) whose total area is smaller than an arbitrary prescribed amount. For instance, if you have $n$ disks of radius $L/n$ covering $\Gamma$, their total area is $n \cdot \pi(L/n)^{2} = \pi L^{2}/n$, and this can be made as small as you like. Are you having trouble with 1. or 2., and if so could you say something about what exactly you're unsure about?

Comment: I do have trouble solving 1 and 2. 
1: I can imagine that the length of each decomposition is $\frac{L}{n}$ but I don't know how to prove that mathematically. 
2: I don't know how to show that, since $\Gamma$ is pretty much arbitrary.The only thing I know is that it is some curve and is piecemeal $C^1$. 

But I got 1.3. thanks  to your argumentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a detailed sketch that (I hope) doesn't spoil all the fun:

Define the *arc length function* by
$$
s(t) = \int_{0}^{t} \|\gamma'(\tau)\|\, d\tau.
$$
Because $\gamma$ is an injective parametrization and piecewise $C^{1}$, the function $s:[0, 1] \to [0, L]$ is strictly increasing and continuously differentiable. (This probably looks obvious to a physicist, but a mathematician requires proof. The idea is, the speed $\|\gamma'\|$ is continuous, non-negative, and does not vanish identically on any open interval, so its integral is strictly increasing.)

1.1. follows at once. (Subdivide the image into equal-length pieces and pick $t_{k}$ accordingly.)

1.2. Note that if $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$, then 
$$
\|\gamma(b) - \gamma(a)\| \leq s(b) - s(a);
\tag{1}
$$
in words, the straight-line distance between two points on $\Gamma$ does not exceed the arc length (along $\Gamma$) between the points.

(Again, this probably looks obvious to a physicist. Here's an argument to satisfy a mathematician: If $\gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$ there's nothing to show. Otherwise, let
$$
u = \frac{\gamma(b) - \gamma(a)}{\|\gamma(b) - \gamma(a)\|}
$$
be the unit vector parallel to the displacement from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$, and observe that if $\theta$ is the angle between $\gamma'(\tau)$ and $u$, then
$$
\gamma'(\tau) \cdot u = \|\gamma'(\tau)\| \cos\theta \leq \|\gamma'(\tau)\|.
$$
Integrating the left-hand side from $a$ to $b$ gives the straight-line distance between the endpoints; integrating the right-hand side gives the arc length.)

Now, for each $k = 1, \dots, n$, let $\gamma(\bar{t}_{k})$ denote the point "halfway along $\Gamma$ between $\gamma(t_{k-1})$ and $\gamma(t_{k})$". That is, let $\bar{t}_{k}$ be the unique point such that $s(\bar{t}_{k}) = (k - \frac{1}{2}) \frac{L}{n}$.

It suffices to show that if $I = [t_{k-1}, t_{k}]$, then the image $\Gamma(I)$ is contained in the disk of radius $\frac{L}{n}$ about $\gamma(\bar{t}_{k})$. This is a special case of (1). (And, of course, $n$ such disks cover $\Gamma$.)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Now I get how to deal with this sort of things.