# $C^1$ curves are regular

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem

I want to show that for any curve $\gamma : [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ which is $C^1([a,b])$ is impossible that the range of $[\frac{\partial \gamma_1}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial \gamma_2}{\partial t}]$ is zero.

I honestly do not know where should I start, or even if it is true. Intuitively, it seems like if the derivative was $(0,0)$ then the function should stay constant in both directions, and I could not think of a geometric interpretation of that.

To give a bit of context, I wanted to show that the curve described has volume zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since I know that the graphic of a function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has measure zero, if I could show that every part of the curve is implicitly definable, then I would have won. But I am missing this step.

Comment: What is you definition for a $C^1$ curve?

Comment: @Tomás Differentiable with partial derivatives continuous.

Comment: This is not true: the constant curve $\gamma(x) = (0,0)$ has zero derivative everywhere but is perfectly $C^1$, and even $C^\infty$ for that matter. As Tomas already said, you'd need some extra conditions on what you consider a curve in $R^2$ for this to hold true. Possibly that the curve image is a $C^1$ submanifold of $R^2$ and the curve parametrized by arc length.

Comment: Related; found by searching this site for "curve measure zero" :) [A piecewise $C^{1}$ curve has Jordan measure zero.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289845).

Comment: Although Andrew D. Hwang's linked question is for injective curves, while yours is not, the answer Andrew provided does not require that injectiveness..